# Missing custom object array when adding them to another array in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to get an array of custom objects called "Travel" from the database.

This Travel object has another custom object array, the one I miss. This object is called "Passenger". My travel has an passenger array. I can see in eclipse debug variables that the main array has all travels and all travels have its passenger array with the correct count of them.

Every object inside the second array has the correct type but they are empty, no attributes at all, in eclipse debug I just can see CLASSNAME, not even the name of the object attributes. So weird to me.

The loop assigning the objects:

```
// Array to exclude
$exc = array();
// Object Travel
$travel = null;
// Main array
$travelArr = array();

// $arr is the result from database
foreach ($arr as $val) {
   // If the new $val is not processed
   if (!in_array($val->vid, $exc)) {
      $exc[] = $val->vid;
      if (!is_null($travel)) 
         // At this point $travel has its passenger perfect.
         // Once the object is added to the main array it loses its passenger attributes
         $travelArr[] = clone $travel;
     unset($travel);
         // Function to pass from SQL to Travel object
     $travel = $this->fromSQLToObject($val);
      } 

      if (!is_null($val->pemail)) {
         $pas = $this->fromSqlToPasseger($val);
     if (!is_null($pas)) 
        $travel->addPassenger($pas);
      }
}
```

Comment: Why do you `unset ($travel)` right before you assign it?

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with my question, I never asked about clone. My question is not related to the problem, I was just wondering why you have unnecessary code there.

Comment: I thought I was answering to another comment I can't see right now, I'm going crazy. If I unset $travel is to avoid bad memory copies and other issues that could happen when variables are not cleaned.

Comment: Maybe you were commenting on olga's answer, which she has deleted.

Answer (score 0):

After one day breaking my brain I've found out it is something related to my eclipse configuration, I can't see the variables in debug but they are there...

Thanks everyone.